# Currency Conversion Web Service With User Input

Tags: service, currency

I want to Consume a Currency Conversion Web service,

Specification is, User should be able to Select Two Countries from Dropdown list on the UI, such that those values should be sent as parameters to the conversion method.

How can I do this ???

Comment: Which language are you planning to use?

Comment: You COULD hire someone who knows what they're doing before taking on a project that's way over their head.

Comment: Where do you think you are going to get the data from?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the realtime exchange rates supplied by sites like [xe.com](http://www.xe.com), though they cost a lot of money to download. [See the download possibilities here](http://www.xe.com/dfs/product.php).

Why would you need a site like this in the first place? Sites like XE already supplies this functionality for free (if you use their own interface).

Comment: I know XE, provide it... But Its my project to need to have that functionality to the users who use the application.